# Make TTS app with python but for other languages

Tags: python, text-to-speech

I want to create TTS app.
I searched and find many libs for this but they are not use my language (Uzbek). If I usethem, result is not correct.
So i want to make own lib for TTS with my own voice. But i can not find way to make this. Who can help. How i make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Uzbek language you can use `eSpeak-NG` with `py-espeak-ng` Python module: https://pypi.org/project/py-espeak-ng/
According to [eSpeak documentation](https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng/blob/master/docs/languages.md), it supports 158 languages, including Uzbek.
Here is example:

```py
from espeakng import ESpeakNG
esng = ESpeakNG()
esng.voice = 'uz'
esng.say('Salom Dunyo')
```

But if you want to use your own voice, take a look at [Real-time Voice Cloning](https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning).
You can take pretrained model and retrain it on your own samples.

Also here is a good manual about setting up `TTS with Real-Time Voice Cloning` environment in Google Colab:
https://medium.com/wavy-engineering/text-to-speech-with-real-time-voice-cloning-16346127742